# Bind customizable views to dynamic models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

We are working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 using ext.net and EF 4.
Data model is mapped using EF4.
Views’ content is rendered from customizable XML files.
Example: Within one view, I can display fields that are related to both objects “customer” and “order”, so from this view I can modify the customer data and also add a new order.

How can we bind the view to the custom model that contains 2 objects (customer and order)? Using non strongly typed views will require a source code that will check all different possibilities (If I remove/add a field to display from the XML file, object constructor and CRUD operations parameters will change also.

We are wondering how can we handle such dynamic application?
Is this a common issue that was raised before? Or is there any solution to use dynamic views bound to custom model (object, xml, etc.)?

Your help is very appreciated, please enlighten me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you're not using strongly typed views? Since you're using EF4 I suppose you'll have POCO objects mapped to your data. Now you can make some plain ViewData to use in your views, and translate your POCOs into the ViewData (maybe with the help of a tool like Automapper). That would be a best practice.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using POCO object but my concern is that views contain attributes from different models. That's why I'm looking for a way to use custom dynamic models where I can specify the objects that will be used in that specific view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you replied to my comment, I can defenitely say that you need strongly typed views. That said, you decide what the model of your view is. If your view needs to manage users and orders at the same time, you can make a class like this:

```
public class MyCustomViewData
{
public IEnumerable<User> Users {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}
```

and then strongly type your view to `MyCustomViewData` and you're set. My example is oversimplified but I think you can get the point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just faced one more issue while analyzing what you just said. Is it possible to create views with ASP.NET htmlhelpers programmatically. I mean from a different project "ViewEngineGenerator" I would like to create view content using htmlhelpers. Is it possible?

Comment: If you're asking if you can make your own extension methods for the HtmlHelper, yes you can. Just create a static class, make extension methods inside for HtmlHelper class and then put the namespace that contains your class in the web.config and you're set.

Comment: Thank you again. But I don't want to create my own extensions. My concern is that is it possible to use the html helpers outside of the aspx view. I'm rendering fields dynamically from XML file using a view generator project that renders the view with content customized with the XML file and I could not use the html helpers to render fileds from this view generator project.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I believe the normal way round this would be to strongly type your view to say 'user' and then on the user object, define a property which is a collection of 'orders'.